# Change configuration of Webjob using Release Management in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, release-management

I am using Release management of Visual Studio Team Services to build my deployment pipeline.

> The application is a ASP.Net MVC deployed in **Azure as Webapp and also contains a WebJob** module to process Queue.

To change the configuration when deploying i use `Tokenization` approach. MSDN [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/azure/change-config-azure-webapps#the-tokenization-approach)

> How can **change the configuration of Webjob using use Tokenization approach**?

The documentation totally misses the scenario, i tried using powershell but the website didn't work either.

Comment: Are you gonna deploy your both webapp and webjob at the same time or separetely ?

Comment: my plan is to deploy in same tier. But if deploying webjob separately would solve the issue.. i am open to that

Comment: Where do you store the configuration settings for the WebJob? app.config or web.config file?

Comment: it's in the app.config

Answer (score 1):

It is almost the same as the link you referred to. The "Tokenize" task in the link change the settings in the specified "web.config" file. You just need to add one more "Tokeize" task in the release definition and set the "Source filename" to the "app.config" file of your WebJob project.

Comment: In the tokenize task, there is a path **-Q "+CWD site/wwwroot**, what would be the value for webjob?

Comment: @SridharVenkat That's the setting for "cURL File Uploader" task that used to upload the updated config file to server, not for tokenize task

Comment: you are right. i guess i need to provide a similar path for webjob app.config as well.. what would the path for app.config

Comment: @SridharVenkat The app.config file is usually renamed to "webjobname.exe.config" and placed in "site/wwwroot/app_data/jobs/continuous/webjobname" folder after deployment. You can check the path of it from Kudu service\Debug Console: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service.

Comment: Yes it works fine... I was able to get this using ftp. Thanks @Eddie i will document here the entire steps

Comment: @SridharVenkat Glad to hear that. :)